# SSMS Hangs on Create Database (but not via T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Environment:   `SQL Server 2008 SP3` - using `SSMS2008` (local or remote) and `SSMS2012` (remote)

Something happened with our SQL Server instance recently.    Nobody is able to create a new database through an SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) interface.   Neither SSMS for 2008, or SSMS for 2012.

What happens is they hang (or appear to hang).    Sit and spin forever, and then the performance of the SQL instance *really* starts to tank while it is chewing away.    CPU usage skyrockets.

Things I've noticed:

1. Telling it to create the MDF/LDFs on a local drive or network drive makes no difference.
2. We've tried disabling the anti-virus tools on both the SSMS machine and SQL instance server, with no change.
3. We've tried using the SSMS on the SQL instance server itself, and it also just spins.  Any SSMS (we've tried three different machines) does the same thing.
4. If I open Windows Explorer and look at the locations I've told it to put the MDF/LDFs, **they are created**.     I see the MDF and LDF show up.
5. As soon as I kill the SSMS process (because it feels like it's hanging), it does some cleanup work and the MDF/LDFs go away.
6. I can successfully use the `CREATE DATABASE` t-sql script in a query window, and it creates the databases fine, fast as can be, like one would expect.
7. FILESTREAM is **not** enabled for the server instance at all.   No database uses it in the instance.

This only started happening recently - and the only thing I found with GoogleFu was a hotfix by Microsoft for SQL2008-SP2, that had to deal with microfilters and antivirii.   This is SP3, so that fix is rolled into it (as well as we disabled AV on the SQL server and our local machines - to be sure).

Any suggestions or ideas?   Is there some trace profile I can start up that would show me what is going on, step by step, to see where the SQL instance seems to be spinning its wheels when I try creating a database through the SSMS interface?

Comment: SQL Server comes with SQL Profiler for tracing all the commands and events in SQL Server. Start -> Run -> search for "sql profiler".

Comment: I've tried running a few traces, and nothing is showing up.  The generic SQL Server Logs themselves also only show me running a trace then stopping it.   Nothing in between.     I've tried running full blown crippling traces, and the default one - and nothing seems out of the ordinary.     I'm asking for help for a specific trace I can watch, or a resolution.    I know where the profiler is....

Comment: Have you checked the model system database for corruption? DBCC CHECKDB (model)

Comment: I did that just now, and it appears to be OK.

`CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'model'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.`

Comment: Is it a production SQL Server?  If not, does restarting the SQL Server service help?  Was there anything recently installed via Windows Updates that may be related?

Comment: It's not a production server, and we've rebooted it a few times since.   We *did* have the datacenter physical machine unexpectedly reboot - and it made our VMs all restart, but besides this ornerous issue - the thing is working as expected.

Comment: Any 3rd party add-ins to the server or SSMS? Auditing applications? Management tools?

Comment: Nope, none of that, and nothing's changed in the few weeks since I've last seen it work, that I can tell.   It's confusing as heck.